# Word 2013 "Track Changes": Autoscroll Next Change to Middle or Top of Page?

Tags: microsoft-word, scrolling, change-tracking

I'm searching for help with an annoying behavior of Word's "Track Changes" review.

While accepting changes, Word autoscrolls from one markup item to the next. Upon reaching an item at the bottom of a page, though, the focus stays right there for future "stepping" through the document, making context difficult to decipher since some surrounding content is below the displayed page.

Is there a way to autoscroll each and every reviewed markup to, say, the middle of a page? If not for every markup step, at least when the currently reviewed markup is near the bottom.

Thank you!